# Duplicate input issue caused by `std::ios_base::sync_with_stdio( false );`

Tags: c++, io, iostream, cin

When I use `std::ios_base::sync_with_stdio( false );` in the below, the program asks for the first input twice while it should ask once.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <limits>


int main( )
{
    // std::ios_base::sync_with_stdio( false ); // uncommenting this line cause
                                                // the said problem

    std::array<char, 168> buffer1 { };
    std::array<char, 168> buffer2 { };

    std::cin.putback( '\n' );
    std::cin.clear( );
    std::cin.ignore( std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max( ), '\n' );
    std::cin.getline( buffer1.data( ), 168 );

    std::cin.putback( '\n' );
    std::cin.clear( );
    std::cin.ignore( std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max( ), '\n' );
    std::cin.getline( buffer2.data( ), 168 );

    std::cout << "\nbuffer1:\n" << buffer1.data( ) << '\n';
    std::cout << "buffer2:\n" << buffer2.data( ) << '\n';
    std::cout << "\nEnd" << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

I want the code to ask for input twice, once for `buffer1` and once for `buffer2` but this happens:

```
32581 // as can be seen, here I enter a random character sequence for buffer 1 but it doesn't store it in buffer1 and asks for input again
12345 // Instead, this sequence gets stored in buffer1
abcde // buffer2 has no problem, this gets stored in buffer2 successfully

buffer1:
12345
buffer2:
abcde

End
```

However, avoiding the use of `std::ios_base::sync_with_stdio( false );` fixes this bug:

```
32581
abcde

buffer1:
32581
buffer2:
abcde

End
```

How should I fix this bug? Why is it happening?

Comment: What `OS` are you using? I have not been able to recreate your issue.

Comment: @WBuck Windows 10 and Command Prompt.

Comment: @WBuck I have tested it both on **Command Prompt** and **PowerShell**.

Comment: Is there any necessary reason to set it false?

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is the first `putback(\n')` fails when you call

```
std::ios_base::sync_with_stdio( false );
```

So the call `ignore` is blocking until you type in something.

In your case, the first line you type in "32581" is ignored.

A solution maybe just remove the first `put` to `ignore` part. I dont think its necessary here.

Comment: Should I change the order of those four functions to fix this bug?

Comment: @digito_evo Updated in my answer. Changing the order may not be a solution.

Comment: This `if (std::cin.putback( '\n' ))` did not solve the issue.

Comment: @digito_evo sorry, the solution is not tested. Try another way. Worked in GCC https://godbolt.org/z/86qWEjfWf

Comment: I figured out another solution based on yours.